# Вывод картинки из шестнадцатеричного цвета

Tags: php, base64, hex

Есть список цветов в шестнадцатеричном формате - пробую преобразовать этот код в base64 формат, чтоб вывести в качестве источника картинки.

```
<?php
$code = "1111ff";
echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode(hex2bin($code))."'>";
?>
```

Но понимаю, что получается что-то не то.

```
<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,ERH/'>
```

Как сделать, чтоб этот код преобразовывался в понимаемую браузером картинку?

Comment: а вы из каких соображений решили, что такой подход в принципе может работать?

Comment: @teran я понимаю, что мой пример практически бессмысленный, но меня интересует, возможно ли это вообще.

Comment: @fixer конечно может, если только вы выведете настоящую jpeg-картинку, а не какие-то непонятные три байта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил данный вопрос через svg.

```
<?php
$hex_code = "1111ff";
list($r, $g, $b) = sscanf($hex_code, "%02x%02x%02x");
$image = "data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg height='30' width='30' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1'><circle cx='15' cy='15' r='30' fill='rgb($r,$g,$b)'/></svg>";
?>
<img src="<?=$image;?>" alt="<?=$hex_code;?>"/>
```

Comment: просто `fill="#$hex_code"`, не нужны там никакие манипуляции с rgb

Comment: @teran с решеткой не работает, тогда нужно кодировать спецсимволы в строке, что не очень удобно для дальнейшей отладки.

Comment: так замените решетку на `%23`.